# what are node fs.createReadStream equivilent in .net C#

Tags: c#, node.js

I am pipeing the following content to a webservice in node that works fine.

```
var content = fs.createReadStream("myfile.zip");
```

but when doing the same on .Net and c# using

```
File.ReadAllBytes("myfile.zip")
```

the service returns an error. Is there any difference to the two methods for reading the data? Will `content.pipe` read the data in a different encoding than .net will and therefore work on node but not .Net.

My full problem is defined here: [Converting a node filestream piped to http request to c# and httpclient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39577969/converting-a-node-filestream-piped-to-http-request-to-c-sharp-and-httpclient)
but i believe the core issue is related to data encoding and the content.pipe of node not behaving similar in .net, hense this more specific question.

Comment: and what error does the server return?

Comment: I dont own the server and the error dont really mean much to the question.  All I can see is that it work from node but not c#, and want to figure out why and concluded its related to how data are read and send. inspecting with fiddler, all headers are the same in the two samples.